# h2 jdbc url... Load balance or fail over?

Tags: url, jdbc, h2

I have the following issue: Two instances of an application on two different systems. And, two h2db server A, B duplication.

two application first connection -> A -> if fail -> B connect.

In Oracle JDBC URL

`jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(LOAD_BALANCE=on)(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)
(HOST=db1ip)(PORT=1521))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)
(HOST=db2ip)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=service_name)))`

In h2db?? How?

Comment: You can use the clustering, but client will connect to all currently available servers at once: https://h2database.com/html/advanced.html#clustering (it means that each update command will be executed on all online servers).

Comment: `jdbc:h2:tcp://server1:9092,server2:9092/path/to/database`